# Getting rid of plaintext hyperlinks before indexing a record in Solr

Tags: regex, solr

I have a field, whose content is used to generate facets from. One particular problem I'd like to solve is the fact that some of my content contains hyperlinks in plaintext i.e `http://google.com`. As a result, I started seeing `http` as one of my top facets. How can I make sure that I filter out the hyperlink content, before I index it? Using a regex filter of some sort?

I know that I can do this pre-processing part on the client side, when I add the records to Solr. Yet, I'd like to keep everything consistent, and part of the Solr pipeline, so I'd like the Solr pre-processor to do this for me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with these components:

1. The [`solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizer`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-UAX29URLEmailTokenizer) preserves the URL as a token
2. The [`solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-PatternReplaceFilter) replaces the URL token with an empty string (search Stack Overflow for a suitable regex pattern)
3. A [`solr.LengthFilterFactory`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-LengthFilter) filters the zero-length token

In schema.xml:

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="..." replacement="" />
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="1000" />
</analyzer>
```

Note that changing the tokenizer from the `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory` may have implications beyond what is described in this answer, so be sure to test.